# Sort on the basis of CheckBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView in which there are multiple columns, There is a check box Column like this:

[image]

I want to sort my datagridview in descending order according to column "weight". But if the checkbox next to weight is checked, that row should go down at the bottom of the list. Finally, I want to have a sorted (in descending order) datagridview according to weight column and I see the unchecked rows first, and then the checked rows. Please help me.

Comment: It depends on how you want to do the sort. If you want to use the built-in Sort you can [use the overload that takes a comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_Sort_System_Collections_IComparer_), which _"allows advanced customization of the sorting feature of the DataGridView class"_ - basically you need to sort by the checkbox column first, then by the weight column.

Comment: in sql you can do `order by [Total Image], Weight desc` which will put all checked rows at the buttom, an sort the rest by weight

Comment: @guidog if sql is used i'd expect this grid to be databound to a datatable, in which case setting `dt.DefaultView.Sort="[TotalImage] ASC, [Weight] DESC";` could be used. If the grid is bound to a ibindinglist (such as bindingsource) it could be set there..

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, so now he already has 3 options

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 List<DataGridViewRow> newRowcheck = new List<DataGridViewRow>();
 List<DataGridViewRow> newRowUncheck = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value) == false)
                {
                    newRowUncheck.Add(row);
                }
                else
                {
                    newRowcheck.Add(row);
                }


            }


            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();


            int RowIndex;

            for (RowIndex = 0; RowIndex < newRowUncheck.Count; RowIndex++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[0].Value = newRowUncheck[RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
                dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = newRowUncheck[RowIndex].Cells[1].Value;

            }


            dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);

            DataGridView tempDataGridView = new DataGridView();
            tempDataGridView.Columns.Add("Column1", "Column1 Name in Text");
            tempDataGridView.Columns.Add("nColumn2", "Column2 Name in Text");

            for (int i = 0; i < newRowcheck.Count; i++)
            {
                tempDataGridView.Rows.Add();
                tempDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = newRowcheck[i].Cells[0].Value;
                tempDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = newRowcheck[i].Cells[1].Value;
            }

            tempDataGridView.Sort(tempDataGridView.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Descending);      

            for (int i = 0; i < tempDataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                dataGridView1.Rows[i + RowIndex - 1].Cells[0].Value = tempDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
                dataGridView1.Rows[i + RowIndex - 1].Cells[1].Value = tempDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But the problem in this code is in sorting of checked items. This code does not sort checked cells. Could you please help me again?!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Still it does not give the correct answer. I will send you a picture showing the result.

Comment: Unfortunately the final result was not sorted in descending order for checked items. I dont know why!

Comment: Please try these inputs: Roy (weight=3), Eli (weight=65), Alis(weight=5), Mery(weight=100) and chck for Alis and Mery. You will see that the final result will not be sorted according to weight in descending order. (By the way, I have changed the index of columns from 0 to 1, because the sorting should be done on column 1).

Comment: did you change this line? if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[1].Value) == false)

Comment: replace like this if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[2].Value) == false)  , because  checkbox in column index 2 , in your dataGridView